# Convert JSON string to List of Dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python 3.7
I want a JSON string key values to be appeared as list ...

```
    print("rv  --->",  type(rv))   # <class 'ValueResult'> returned from database
    print("rv.value  --->", type(rv.value)) # <class 'dict'>
    # shows {'ACTION_CODE': 'S', 'ARRIVAL_DATE': '03-JUL-19', 'BIT_FLAGS': '1082131456'
    print(rv.value)
    print("rv.value.items() ---> ", type(rv.value.items())) #<class 'dict_items'>
    print(json.loads(json.dumps(rv.value))) # used this no help
```

I am expecting this to be returned as below list of (Dictionaries) :

```
[
    {"ACTION_CODE": "S"},
    {"ARRIVAL_DATE": "03-JUL-19"} ,
    {"BIT_FLAGS": "1082131456" }                    
]
```

Comment: Can't you play with output of the second statement where you get a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension

```
a={'ACTION_CODE': 'S', 'ARRIVAL_DATE': '03-JUL-19', 'BIT_FLAGS': '1082131456'}
print([ {key:value} for key,value in a.items()])
```

OUTPUT

```
[{'ACTION_CODE': 'S'}, {'ARRIVAL_DATE': '03-JUL-19'}, {'BIT_FLAGS': '1082131456'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the dictionary to a list of dictionaries using a list comprehension:

```py
>>> data = {'ACTION_CODE': 'S', 'ARRIVAL_DATE': '03-JUL-19', 'BIT_FLAGS': '1082131456'}
>>> output = [{k: v} for k, v in data.items()]
>>> print(output)
# [{'ACTION_CODE': 'S'}, {'ARRIVAL_DATE': '03-JUL-19'}, {'BIT_FLAGS': '1082131456'}]
```

However, it seems unusual that you would want to use a list of dictionaries, rather than the dictionary itself. Converting your data to a list of dictionaries would (presumably) make it harder to use in your code. Instead, you should just access the keys directly:

```
>>> data['ACTION_CODE']
'S'
```

Is this possibly a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?